# php pagination, something is wrong

Tags: php, mysql

I found a tutorial according pagination.
http://papermashup.com/easy-php-pagination/

I tried the code and it work. but every time the first index is reload(first result in pagination).

I got this message.

> Notice: Undefined index: page in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sim\registrar\index.php on line 207

how can I remove this message?

here's the code..

```
$targetpage = "index.php";
$limit = 3;

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM advisoryclass";

$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));

$total_pages = $total_pages['num'];

$stages = 3;

    $page = mysql_escape_string($_GET['page']);//this part

if($page){
$start = ($page - 1) * $limit;

}else{

$start = 0;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming `page` is set when that's not always going to be the case; hence the error.

Change this:

```
$page = mysql_escape_string($_GET['page']);//this part
```

To:

```
$page = ( isset( $_GET['page'] ) ) ? mysql_escape_string( $_GET['page'] ) : 1;
```

In the code above we're checking the page `$_GET` variable has been set and using 1 as a fallback.

You may want to look at the functions you're using with the database too.

Comment: @MaggsWeb Why? The following line will reduce page by 1 so if page is 1 then the query starts from 0.

Comment: `if($page)`...  If $page == 1, then this evaluates to `true`

Comment: @MaggsWeb Correct and `if ( $page )` set start to `$page - 1`. If the page is 1 then `$page - 1` (start) is 0. The code that determines the start position should be revised anyway given that it will always be true.

Answer (score 1):

add a check in order to see if the parameter is in the get array:

```
$page = mysql_escape_string(isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0);
```

this is a ternary comparison in order to make it shorter than an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle if $page does not exist.

```
$page = mysql_escape_string(isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0);
```